# Natural Numbers as Vectors via Factorization?

Tags: number-theory

[Apparently](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/2479) factorization of integers allows one to interpret natural numbers as vectors so that "$\gcd$ and $\mathrm{lcm}$ become component-wise $\min$ and $\max$". Could anybody explain this in more detail and provide an example or two?

Comment: Why not ask the person who posted that answer to elaborate?

Comment: @Aran No, the elements of the vectors are the *exponents* of the primes, i.e. $\,n = 2^a 3^b 5^c\cdots\,$ has exponent vector $\,e(n) = [a,b,c,\ldots],\,$ so $\,e(nm) = e(n)+e(m),\,$ and $\,e(n^k) = k\, e(n).\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the fact that natural numbers have a unique factorization into prime powers sounds a lot like the theorem that vectors in a vector space have a unique representation (as a linear combination) in terms of the basis vectors (for a given basis).

If we think of the prime numbers are (infinitely many) "basis vectors", we can represent all natural numbers as their "linear combinations". For example

$150 = 2\times 3\times 5^2 = \vec{2}+\vec{3}+2\cdot\vec{5}$

where, of course, the vector "addition" is just multiplication. Similarly

$5500 = 2^2\times 5^3 \times 11 = 2\cdot\vec{2} + 3\cdot\vec{5} + \vec{11}$

Now what is $\gcd(220, 5500)$? Component-wise $\min\lbrace \vec{2}+\vec{3}+2\cdot\vec{5} + 0\cdot\vec{11}, 2\cdot\vec{2} + 0 \cdot \vec{3} + 3\cdot\vec{5} + \vec{11} \rbrace$ = $\vec{2} + 2\cdot\vec{5} = 50$.

Similarly

$\mathrm{lcm}(220, 5500) = \max\lbrace \vec{2}+\vec{3}+2\cdot\vec{5} + 0\cdot\vec{11}, 2\cdot\vec{2} + 0 \cdot \vec{3} + 3\cdot\vec{5} + \vec{11} \rbrace$
$=2\cdot \vec{2} + \vec{3} + 3\cdot \vec{5} + \vec{11} = 16500$.

The zero "vector" would be $1 = 2^0 \times 3^0 \times 5^0 \times \ldots = 0\cdot\vec{2} + 0 \cdot\vec{3} + 0\cdot\vec{5} + \ldots$, and if we allow negative "scalars", then we would be able to express all rational numbers in the same manner. For example, $\frac{22}{7} = \vec{2} - \vec{7} + \vec{11}$.

This is still not a vector space, though, as the scalars only form a ring (the ring of integers), and not a field. This is a [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 3):

I hope the idea is clear from the following example.

- $m=51450=2\times3\times5^2\times7^3$, think of $m$ as the vector $(1,1,2,3,0,0,\ldots)$.
- $n=16500=2^2\times3\times5^3\times11$, think of $n$ as the vector $(2,1,3,0,1,0,0,\ldots)$.
- The gcd of $m,n$ is $2\times3\times5^2$, think of this as the vector $(1,1,2,0,0,\ldots)$ in which each element is the minimum of the two corresponding elements above.
- And similarly for the lcm.